# Razor pages identity login button doesn't login

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I've recently discovered an annoying issue with my identity razor pages. I have disabled the register page (followed all the steps listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#disable-register-page)), and that seems to work alright. If I navigate (via url) to the register page, it redirects me to the login page, which is good. However, if I then fill in my credentials and press the login button, it brings me to my apps homescreen, without actually logging in. I then have to renavigate to the login page, and then it works fine. I'm having a really hard time finding the problem, so any help is appreciated. I didn't change much about the code, but here is some of the login page code:

login.cshtml:

```
@page
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
}

<head>
</head>

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <section>
            <form id="account" method="post">
                @*<h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>*@
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe">
                            <input asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>
                        <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
                    </p>
                    @*<p>
                        <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Register as a new user</a>
                    </p>*@
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

tasks in login.cshtml.cs:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
```

important parts startup:

```
 services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = "UserID";
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();


            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();


            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Administrator", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimsStore.Claims[0].Type, ClaimsStore.Claims[0].Value);
                });
                options.AddPolicy("User", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimsStore.Claims[1].Type, ClaimsStore.Claims[1].Value);
                });
            });
```

```
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseIdentityServer();
 app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Is this core 3.1? can you post your code in startup e.g. services.AddIdentity() .AddAuthentication() .AddAuthorization() Also the order of calls in startup Configure() matters, .UseAuthentication() must be before .UseMvc();

Comment: It is indeed core 3.1. I updated my post to include the code in startup you mentioned

Comment: Looks like you are mixing up standard login pages with JWT authentication with identityserver. If you use JWT usually it is for API calls with a javascript client. You need to store and send the JWT token in the header. See this doc page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1